# Threads not starting same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I know there is a lot of question about this topic, I've reviewed all of them and couldn't find a workable solution.

I'm starting 10 thread simultaneously in WPF appliciation.

First four threads start at the same time, but other jobs start lagging about 5-10 seconds. I share the test data below.

How can I solve this problem?

```
private void DoParallel()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            DoSomeWork();
          });
        }
    }
}
```

- 27.02.2019 17:31:33
- 27.02.2019 17:31:33
- 27.02.2019 17:31:33
- 27.02.2019 17:31:33
- 27.02.2019 17:31:35
- 27.02.2019 17:31:40
- 27.02.2019 17:31:46
- 27.02.2019 17:31:52
- 27.02.2019 17:32:00
- 27.02.2019 17:32:02

Comment: Is `DoSomeWork` doing some really heavy computation?

Comment: DoSomeWork takes about 10 seconds. I'm calling soap service.

Comment: This depends on so many things. I'd suggest you read a book about the TPL.

Comment: Depending on what `DoSomeWork` does all your CPUs might be busy making other threads wait. How should we know?

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. Even with threads starting "at the same time" is highly improbable. You can't execute more threads than there are cores, so in a quad machine only *4* threads can run at the same time and execute that `Console.WriteLine`. The OS will evict the current threads and schedule the other to run at some point.

Comment: Instead of starting tasks, use the service proxy's Task-based methods to execute the calls asynchronously. This *doesn't* block any threads while awaiting for a response

Comment: You are observing the behavior of the ThreadPool on a machine with 4 cpu cores.  You could experiment with TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning to tell the Task class that DoSomeWork() takes a while.  It is a corner-case, it only takes a bit longer than too long, so you do have to check if you're actually ahead.  Pay attention to the cpu load as visible in Task Manager, Processes tab.  If it is now close to 100% then you won't be ahead without spending money.

Comment: I would consider parallel foreach. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop Control returns to the line after the parallel once all threads are finished. Which could be  a plus - or a minus.

Comment: You are starting tasks, not threads. There may be threads involved, but you don't know how many, if any. If you want to test threads then use threads.

Comment: It seems that the reason for the delay is cpu. Because I'm starting Tasks, not threads. **TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning** option allows them to start at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  The default [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.7.2) is using the .NET [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.7.2), which may be saturated and you have limited control over it.

If you wanted to, you could create your own `TaskScheduler` to change this behavior.  For example, if desired, you could create one that launches a separate thread.

This behavior would become even more pronounced if your code fired off even more Tasks than it does already:

```
private void DoParallel()
{
    //This will over-saturate the ThreadPool unless you use your own TaskScheduler
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
         Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            DoSomeWork();
          });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I create my own TaskScheduler

Comment: @ErhanUrun This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.7.2) has a full code example for how to implement a custom `TaskScheduler`.  In short, you need to subclass it.